Postgres install on Ubuntu 24 - can't connect
I have installed postgresql on my ubuntu 24 box using  apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib - the install works fine no issues. I can start postgresql fine as well.
However when I try 'psql' I get error
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?

I think the reason may be that no postgres user is created on install. When I do getent passwd postgres nothing is returned
Also /var/run/postgresql doesn't exist
This seems like an odd one, I can't find anything on it. Perhaps the install is silent failing? Any help really appreciated

I start using sudo service postgresql start and sudo service postgresql status returns ● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS      Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; prese>      Active: active (exited) since Mon 2024-08-12 11:00:36 NZST; 1h 41min ago    Main PID: 820 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)         CPU: 6ms

At command line run pg_lsclusters to see what Postgres servers are running and what port they are listening on. The error is occurring because either the server is not  running or it is running on a different port then 5432.

All that show is that the attempt to start it successfully initiated, not that it fully succeeded.  Look in the postgres-specific log file.

Kindly check the following:

Check necessary permissions for the user to create /var/run/postgresql directory. Mainly these types of issues occur due to permissions

Also check if the user has permissions to access installation directories ?
 [postgres@rocky8 ~]$ ls -l /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
 srwxrwxrwx. 1 postgres postgres 0 
 /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432




This is not an answer it is a comment. Either make this an answer or delete it.

Thanks. Which user do you mean? The local user I generally use (with sudo as needed) Or the postgres user? I have re-installed and a 'postgres' user seems to have been created. However it has a password and I do not know the password...

Kindly check the following:

Check necessary permissions for the user to create /var/run/postgresql directory. Mainly these types of issues occur due to permissions
Also check if the user has permissions to access installation directories ?

Check if postgres user has necessary permissions to create these directories
